# How to build a DataGenerator/ Sequence for Multi Loss and Multi Output Model in Keras (Tensorflow2)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, siamese-network

I'm working on a model where I have two losses and 2 different outputs. One output takes `y` as an Image just like [Autoencoder](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) / [U-Net](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) architecture. The other output is simple Binary classification which takes as 0/1.

So what I'm trying to pull off is `Siamese Based Unet`. Basically Reconstruct the image based on `mae` loss and create a branch from Bottleneck layer so that it can predict whether 2 images are similar or not based on the Eunclidean distance.

`Keras` has a `ImageDataGenerator` where you can use `class_mode='input'` to generate a corresponding image as y label and also `class_mode=binary` to generate a 0/1 value given in the column. But how can I generate both things in the same generator. Problem is that the `Siamese Branch` will accept 2 inputs at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Sequence object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)
. It allows one to create custom data generators. The idea is to subclass Sequence and then override methods **len**, **getitem**. **len** should return number of batches in the sequence. The logic that returns the source and target pair is written inside **getitem**. It should return a batch of data. Incase of multi input models, you can write **getitem** such that its output data include a dictionary mapping to the input layer of your model(key=layername). Similarly for an output tensor. More information can be found in the link to the official doc I have added above. Best

**Edit**

This is the gist as per my understanding of your problem.:

```
class Dataset(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, filenames, batchsize, shape):
        self.filenames = filenames # List of filenames
        self.batchsize = batchsize
        self.shape = shape # Shape to which image should be 
        # resized

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.filenames) // batchsize

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        i = idx * self.batchsize
        
        X_1 = np.zeros((self.batchsize, self.shape[0], self.shape[1], 3)
        y = np.zeros((self.batchsize, --, --, ..., --)) # Depends on
        # your target choice

        filenames = self.filenames[i:i+self.batchsize]

        for index, filename in enumerate(filenames):
            image = cv2.imread(filename)
            
            # Preprocess
            image = your_preprocess(image)

            X[index] = image

         
         # You can include your pipeline for other
         # Input also.

         # Similarly obtain target values and load to y.

         
         return {"layername": X_1, "layername": X_2}, {"layername": y}
```

Comment: Yeah I know `Sequence` but I'm unable to generate the batches actually. What I was looking for is the logic here.

Comment: I have added a gist with the answer. Hoping I got your problem as intended. Best.

Comment: I understand your code. Maybe I did nit make myself clear. Let us suppose we have a `batch_size=1`, then My model will take 2 images `layer1:X1`, `layer2:X2`. So in the `UNET` branch, it'll try to reconstruct both `Sequentially` so it'll predict `out1:X1` and then `out1:X2` . Also, Parallelly, it'll try to predict whether X1 is equal to X2 or not. and output `out2:0/1`. I don't know if I'm thinking straight or not. Not that if it can be achieved or not.